# F# modules, any way to simply import another file?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code

I'm working in vscode and F#.

- I want to use another files function
- both files are inside the same directory

Is there any easy way to import another F#-file and use its function from another F# file?

Comment: Yes this answer my exact question! 
I was searching fo this on google and here on SO but I couldn't find any good explaination. What do I do now with this topic? Thank you for the link and sorry!

Comment: You can delete this question if you like, or wait until 3 other people confirm it is a duplicate, then it will be closed. BTW, I found the duplicate by searching for "#load f#" because I wanted to provide further reading in the answer and the dupe came up. Leaving it as a duplicate might give better SEO on the other answer :).

Comment: Okay, so now its closed, right Dave? And thank you I didn't know the #load would import other files :) I thought you used 'namespaces' for that. Sorry for the confusion and thanks again!